# Admob interstitial doesn't show up

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I've set a button that shows an interstitial Admob when pressed.

That's my code:

**-Declaration**

```
    var AdsInterstitial:GADInterstitial!
```

**-View did load**

```
    AdsInterstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "Id sample number")
    let request = GADRequest()
    AdsInterstitial.loadRequest(request)
```

**-Button Pressed**

```
    AdsInterstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
    AdsInterstitial = NewInterstitial()
```

**-Function that generates new Ad**

```
    func NewInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial{

        let AdsInterstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "Id sample number")
        AdsInterstitial.loadRequest(GADRequest())
        return AdsInterstitial

    }
```

When  I click the button I get this error: " *Cannot present interstitial. It is not ready.*"

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are getting means you are pressing the button to show ads too soon. When you are pressing the button you should have an if statement checking if the ad is ready or not like this.

```
if AdsInterstitial.isReady { 
    AdsInterstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
}
```

Also instead of creating the new Interstitial while the ad is being displayed you should create the new one when they press the "X" button like this

```
func interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
    AdsInterstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
}
```

For more information you can visit Googles site [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/interstitial).